# How to split two data in one array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and want to split two data that contain in one array element.

Here is the code :

```js
const array = ["1 Boston 4 11", "2 Florida 6 14\n3 Texas 5 12", "4 California 7 13"];

array.map(x => {
  return (
    console.log(x.split(" "))
  )
});
```

`array[1]` contain two data : `2 Florida 6 14` and `3 Texas 5 12`. I need to split `array[1]` to two different arrays with each data.

Result i expect :

```
[
  "1",
  "Boston",
  "4",
  "11"
]
[
  "2",
  "Florida",
  "6",
  "14"
]
[
  "3",
  "Texas",
  "5",
  "12"
]
[
  "4",
  "California",
  "7",
  "13"
]
```

Anyone can please help me to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split for each line break and then for each whitespace

```js
const array = ["1 Boston 4 11", "2 Florida 6 14\n3 Texas 5 12", "4 California 7 13"];
console.log(array.flatMap(x => x.split("\n")).map(x => x.split(" ")));
```

As kemicofa explained not all browsers support Array#flatMap. The recommended [alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative) for flatMap is a combination of Array#reduce and Array#concat:

```js
const array = ["1 Boston 4 11", "2 Florida 6 14\n3 Texas 5 12", "4 California 7 13"];
console.log(array.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(x.split("\n")), []).map(x => x.split(" ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flatMap) is not cross-compatible on IE or Edge. Here is an alternative with [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join) and [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/split)

```js
const data = ["1 Boston 4 11", "2 Florida 6 14\n3 Texas 5 12", "4 California 7 13"];

const res = data.join("\n").split("\n").map(item=>item.split(" "));

console.log(res);
```